[drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
i have a fresh install of ubuntu 24.04. It appears that it has installed propriety nvidia drivers itself.
But i'm just concerned by this message and the general slowness of my computer display.
[   32.843227] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership

nvidia-smi                                                        ✔  10:54:21 
Sun Jun 16 10:54:46 2024
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 535.171.04             Driver Version: 535.171.04   CUDA Version: 12.2     |
|-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name                 Persistence-M | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp   Perf          Pwr:Usage/Cap |         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                                         |                      |               MIG M. |
|=========================================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4070 ...    Off | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| N/A   42C    P8               5W /  80W |    505MiB /  8188MiB |     10%      Default |
|                                         |                      |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                            |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                            GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                             Usage      |
|=======================================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      2882      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                          138MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      3277      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                        208MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      4467      G   /usr/local/bin/alacritty                      9MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      5421      G   ...seed-version=20240614-130101.053000       79MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      6176      G   /usr/bin/gnome-control-center                10MiB |

